# Using a degrading corrupted hard disk with a brand new one. Is this ok?

Tags: hard-drive

My old 500GB hard drive started to have bad sectors and is slowly going down. So, I bought a new 1TB Seagate drive. I first attached the 500GB drive as the first primary drive and installed Windows. I want Windows boot loader to be placed in the old drive so it won't conflict with my Linux system. But the actual Windows OS (including C drive) is placed on my new hard drive.

After this, I attached the new drive as the primary and installed Linux. Now if I want to reinstall Windows, I can do it without any issues by simply setting the old drive as the primary. So the Linux system will be untouched.

Questions:

- Is it a good idea to set it up like this?
- Will the old degrading drive have an impact on the new one?
- The old drive is slower than the new one. Won't I be able to get the maximum speed out of the new drive even when it's used to install everything (including the OS)?
- When I ran the Windows Experience Index, I was using the old drive as primary. Did it get the hard drive ratings from the old drive? What if I run it now with the new drive as the primary?

Comment: If only the boot sector is on the old drive, there is no performance impact on your new drive.

Comment: Another thing... when I ran the Windows Experience Index, I was using the old drive as the primary. Did it got the hard drive ratings from the old drive? What if I run it now with the new drive as the primary?

Comment: @EApubs Thanks for the accept. Feel free to upvote if you feel it's good information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When bad sectors are being reported, you can't trust the information to be safe on the hard drive anymore. I would recommend JUST using the new hard drive, and backing up what ever data you can from the old 500GB drive. There is no point in keeping it, as it *will* go belly up

Answer (score 0):

If your old drive dies, you end up with a corrupted bootloader, which could be an issue depending on your skills.

Other than that, there will be no impact.

Try running the WEI again, shouldnt make any difference though